# Error trying to installing django non-rel on windows 7 system

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-nonrel

I am installing django-nonrel 1.4 on Windows 7, with python 2.73, GoogleAppEngine-1.8.2.msi

I have renamed the folder django-testapp-testapp-1.4 as just django-testapp

I then copied the following folders to inside the django-testapp

autoload, dbindexer, django, djangoappengine, djangotoolbox

So the final folder structure looks like:

```
django-testapp

    autoload

    dbindexer

    django

    djangoappengine

    djangotoolbox
```

I then ran manage.py runserver
and got the following error stack trace.

```
C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp>manage.py ru
nserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\mana
ge.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\core\management\__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
goappengine\management\commands\runserver.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.db import connections
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\db\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
go\db\utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\dbin
dexer\base.py", line 54, in DatabaseWrapper
return Wrapper(merged_settings, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\dbin
dexer\base.py", line 37, in __init__
super(BaseDatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp\djan
goappengine\db\base.py", line 290, in __init__
self.ops = DatabaseOperations(self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

C:\Users\Laurence\Documents\python_google_app_engine\django-testapp>
```

I'm hoping somebody understands this and can tell me where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatabaseOperations is defined by django, and used by djangotoolbox and djangoappengine.

Looks like the code in djangoappengine is not matching the code in django.

Make sure you have the appropriate versions of each installed.  My guess is that you have the latest djangoappengine but not the latest version of djangon-nonrel.

Comment: Thank you dragonx your are right. I was using the instructions from the following page. http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine                     It turns out that the link to django-nonrel takes you to version 1.3 which is deprecated. Apart from django-autoload all the folders need to be 1.4